# Конфликт iptables (фаервола) и nodejs

Tags: linux, node.js, администрирование, iptables, vesta

Всем привет. Пытаюсь поднять сервер на nodejs, сервер заводится, но подключиться к нему не удается. Когда отключаю фаервол - iptables в панели vestacp сервер становится доступен. С чем это связано, и как избежать ? Заранее спасибо за любую помощь !)))

Comment: Посмотрите решение http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode

Comment: *как избежать ?* — логичный ответ: не включать то, что вы назвали «фаерволом».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin нехорошо давать такие советы. Правильный ответ: добавить в файерволл исключение для порта на котором работает nodejs.

Comment: @AK, *нехорошо* — не знаю. вполне возможно. // я уверен лишь в том, что ответ — логичный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зайдите в косоль управления сервером как root по ssh

```
>ssh roor@ip_servera
```

и откройте нужный порт для nodejs

```
>iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport PORT -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

/вместо PORT укажите нужный порт, например 3000

сохраните данные

```
>service iptables save
```

перезагрузите iptables

```
>service iptables restart
```

если вы под Win, то используйте как ssh клиент, например - PuTTY 
Все тоже самое вы можете сделать и через панель vesta, просто указав нужный порт.

для nodejs

```
server.listen(3000);
```